# sync_state pg_stat_replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-12

I created 2 tables replication with these procedure :

1. Create publication : `CREATE PUBLICATION pub_1 FOR TABLE table_1, table_2;`
2. Create subscription for table 1 : `CREATE SUBSCRIPTION sub_1 CONNECTION 'host=10.100.9.45 port=5432 user=username password=mypwd dbname=db_profile' PUBLICATION pub_1 with (copy_data = false);`
3. Create subscription for table 2 : `CREATE SUBSCRIPTION sub_2 CONNECTION 'host=10.100.9.45 port=5432 user=username password=mypwd dbname=db_profile' PUBLICATION pub_2 with (copy_data = false);`

Question :

1. When I do `select from pg_stat_replication`, there are 2 different sync_state : `POTENTIAL` and `SYNC`. This replication only happens between 2 servers: 1 master and 1 slave.

Here it says :

> **Sync** is the state of synchronous-standby server of the *highest priority among all working standbys* (except asynchronous-servers).
> **Potential** is the state of spare synchronous-standby server of the *second or lower priority among the all working standbys* (except
> asynchronous-servers).

I only have 1 server as destination. I am expecting both `sync_state` to be all "**SYNC**" since they both on the same server. Why do they have 2 different `sync_state` as if there are 2 slaves ?

2. There was a time when the subscription is broken. `pg_stat_replication` only shows 1 record instead of 2. Why the replication record suddenly missing ?

Thanks